# RedBeanPhp how to create an active record model

Tags: php, redbean

anyone know it is possible to convert this:

```
$u = R::dispense('users');
$u->login = $this->login;
$u->password = $this->password;
R::store($u);
```

into this:

```
class User
{
    var $login;
    var $password;
    var $id;

    public function save() {
        $u = R::dispense('users');
        $u->login = $this->login;
        $u->password = $this->password;
        $this->id = R::store($u);
    }
}

$u = new User();
$u->login = 'login';
$u->password = 'pass';
$u->save();
```

but without using code on save some thing like this

```
public function save() {
    R::store($this);
}
```

Im sick and tired of rewritting statements like $u->login = $this->login;

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a users model that extends Redbean's simple model like so:

```
class Model_users extends \RedBean_SimpleModel
{
    private $_login = 'My default login name';
    private $_password = 'My default not so secret password';

    // The following method is executed right before an insert or update
    function update()
    {
        $this->bean->login = $this->_login;
        $this->bean->password = $this->_password;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
$user = R::dispense('users');
R::store($user);
```

Good luck!